# Certification in secure software development?

Tags: professional-education, software

I'm looking for available certifications for software developers and for companies that produce software products.

Are any available?

Comment: there are many hits for this question if you search - is there something in particular that you are looking for?

Comment: No, I'm interesting in all possible opportunities

Comment: Then this is answered with a Google search.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for training/certification of individuals for secure coding, SANS.org is a good resource. Their training is very good and the certifications are well respected. 
https://www.sans.org/curricula/secure-software-development

If you are looking for a security benchmark certification for software products produced by a company, the CIS Security Software Vendor Membership is a good program: 
https://benchmarks.cisecurity.org/membership/certified/overview/

Comment: Thanks, it's usefull
Is any courses with certificates about SDL? Or any other kinds of general development?

Comment: Each of the SANS secure development courses cover SDLC. Take a look at the course syllabus for each class to see if they have what you're looking for. The SANS link I posted will show you which ones have a related certification.